# Combining Text and Hyperlink Into Text that is Hyperlinked

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, excel-2013

I have text in column A and URLs in column B.

I want the merged A&B shown in column C.

Example:

Column A | Column B | Column C
Product 1 | google_dot_com | Product 1 (with hyperlink to url)
Product 2 | yahoo_dot_com | Product 2 (with hyperlink to url)
Product 3 | stackoverflow_dot_com | Product 3 (with hyperlink to url)

Here is an image. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuUUh.jpg]

This is different from just referencing the cells and using the HYPERLINK(A1,B1) and then copying it down column C.

Here is a small test file I created that you can download if my above example wasn't clear enough. http://www.filedropper.com/stacker-help

Using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013, Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

`=HYPERLINK(B2,A2)` should work as per your image requirement. Please check

store the link(column B) in text format

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the CONCATENATE-Funktion in Excel, e.g.`=CONCATENATE(A1;B1)`.
If you need the square bracets just add them in eg.g `=CONCATENATE(A1;"[";B1;"]")`.

The function-names in Excel depend on your language, you might have to use a translated version (in Germany 'VERKETTEN', other languages see http://en.excel-translator.de/CONCATENATE/).
And it gets better: in german you need ";" to seperate the parameters, in english it's a ",".

Translating funktion-names like in Excel should be considered a crime.

Comment: I don't I was too clear, here is an image of what I want it to look like. http://i.imgur.com/KU2QXFD.jpg

Comment: You mentioned The Hyperlink funktion, it seems to work for me the way you wanted: =HYPERLINK(B1;A1)

Comment: The issue with using the hyperlink function is that it leaves the formula in tact, which I do not want. Ideally I wanted to be able to copy the cells straight from Excel and then paste them elsewhere, while not relying on the specific references.

I have posted the answer that solved my issue below, so take a look if you are curious.

Thank you so much for your help either way. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Normally Excel copies the Contends, not the functions. If  you paste in Excel, it can happen, that you paste the function insteas, for that you can paste as values (klick on the little arrow under paste)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer I was looking for, here is the VBA code I used.

```
Sub MergingCells()
For i = 2 To Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("sheet1").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(i, 3), Address:="http://" &     Cells(i,     2).Value, TextToDisplay:=Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
End Sub
```